# Articles about data analysis workflow

Tags: regression, bayesian, references, regression-strategies, exploratory-data-analysis

I am a non-statistician. I have to write a non-English article about my data analysis workflow for a particular epidemiological regression analysis that I conducted.

The article will cover my workflow approximately as follows: observatory data analysis > explanatory data analysis > drawing causal graphs > simple regression models > more complex regression models > parametrizing regression model ...

To back the new article with good references, **could you please suggest some good articles about data analysis workflow?** Book chapter recommendations are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One excellent reference is

- McGowan, Lucy D'Agostino, Roger D. Peng, and Stephanie C. Hicks. "Design Principles for Data Analysis." https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.05689

It also has several citations of other good references.